# Cannot access json correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json structure:

```
 {"note":"{\"quartal\":3,\"jahr\":2014,\"id\":3,\"number\":\"23\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Konsiliaruntersuchung\",\"diagnoses\":[{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Enzephalitis nach Varizellen-Infektion [kodiere zusätzlich G05.1*]\",\"id\":40},{\"code\":\"H26.2\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Komplizierte Katarakt\",\"id\":39},{\"code\":\"H01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Augenlidekzem\",\"id\":42},{\"code\":\"C63.-\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Schornsteinfegerkrebs\",\"id\":44},{\"code\":\"H90.2\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Konduktive Schwerhörigkeit\",\"id\":36},{\"code\":\"E50.4\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Vitamin-A-Mangel mit xerotischer Keratitis [kodiere zusätzlich H19.8*]\",\"id\":38},{\"code\":\"A30.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Polare gutartige Lepra\",\"id\":43},{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Varizellen-Enzephalitis [kodiere zusätzlich G05.1*]\",\"id\":41},{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Varizellen-Enzephalitis  (G05.1*)\",\"id\":46}],\"entrys\":[{\"nummer\":\"03322\",\"beschreibung\":\"Aufzeichnung eines Langzeit-EKG von mindestens 18 Stunden Dauer\",\"id\":22},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":21},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":20},{\"nummer\":\"02400\",\"beschreibung\":\"13C-Harnstoff-Atemtest\",\"id\":17},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":15},{\"nummer\":\"02400\",\"beschreibung\":\"13C-Harnstoff-Atemtest\",\"id\":2}]}","notes":["{\"quartal\":3,\"jahr\":2014,\"id\":2,\"number\":\"00\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Ambulant\",\"diagnoses\":[{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Enzephalitis nach Varizellen-Infektion [kodiere zusätzlich G05.1*]\",\"id\":40},{\"code\":\"H26.2\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Komplizierte Katarakt\",\"id\":39},{\"code\":\"H01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Augenlidekzem\",\"id\":42},{\"code\":\"C63.-\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Schornsteinfegerkrebs\",\"id\":44},{\"code\":\"H90.2\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Konduktive Schwerhörigkeit\",\"id\":36},{\"code\":\"E50.4\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Vitamin-A-Mangel mit xerotischer Keratitis [kodiere zusätzlich H19.8*]\",\"id\":38},{\"code\":\"A30.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Polare gutartige Lepra\",\"id\":43},{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Varizellen-Enzephalitis [kodiere zusätzlich G05.1*]\",\"id\":41},{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Varizellen-Enzephalitis  (G05.1*)\",\"id\":46}],\"entrys\":[{\"nummer\":\"03322\",\"beschreibung\":\"Aufzeichnung eines Langzeit-EKG von mindestens 18 Stunden Dauer\",\"id\":22},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":21},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":20},{\"nummer\":\"02400\",\"beschreibung\":\"13C-Harnstoff-Atemtest\",\"id\":17},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":15},{\"nummer\":\"02400\",\"beschreibung\":\"13C-Harnstoff-Atemtest\",\"id\":2}]}","{\"quartal\":3,\"jahr\":2014,\"id\":1,\"number\":\"43\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Notfall\",\"diagnoses\":[{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Enzephalitis nach Varizellen-Infektion [kodiere zusätzlich G05.1*]\",\"id\":40},{\"code\":\"H26.2\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Komplizierte Katarakt\",\"id\":39},{\"code\":\"H01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Augenlidekzem\",\"id\":42},{\"code\":\"C63.-\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Schornsteinfegerkrebs\",\"id\":44},{\"code\":\"H90.2\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Konduktive Schwerhörigkeit\",\"id\":36},{\"code\":\"E50.4\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Vitamin-A-Mangel mit xerotischer Keratitis [kodiere zusätzlich H19.8*]\",\"id\":38},{\"code\":\"A30.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Polare gutartige Lepra\",\"id\":43},{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Varizellen-Enzephalitis [kodiere zusätzlich G05.1*]\",\"id\":41},{\"code\":\"B01.1\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Varizellen-Enzephalitis  (G05.1*)\",\"id\":46}],\"entrys\":[{\"nummer\":\"03322\",\"beschreibung\":\"Aufzeichnung eines Langzeit-EKG von mindestens 18 Stunden Dauer\",\"id\":22},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":21},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":20},{\"nummer\":\"02400\",\"beschreibung\":\"13C-Harnstoff-Atemtest\",\"id\":17},{\"nummer\":\"02401\",\"beschreibung\":\"H2-Atemtest\",\"id\":15},{\"nummer\":\"02400\",\"beschreibung\":\"13C-Harnstoff-Atemtest\",\"id\":2}]}"]}
```

When i type into my console `data['note']` it returns the `note`-node correctly but somehow i cannot access the level above:

```
 data['note']['quartal']
 => undefined
```

What do i wrong? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S74Td/ Thanks

Comment: Your `note` value is a string, not a json object. It should start with `{"note":{"quartal":...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `note` is not an object, so it doesn't have a `quartal` property.

The value is a *string*. That string appears to be a representation of a JSON text, so you could parse it into an object with `JSON.parse` and then access it.

```
var note = JSON.parse(data.note);
alert(note.quartal);
```

You would probably be better off changing your original data so you have an object instead of a string of JSON text there in the first place though.

Answer (score 1):

You must decode **note**:

```
 var test = JSON.parse(data.note);
 console.log(test.quartal);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
var a = JSON.parse(data.note);
console.log("OP: "+a.quartal);
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/S74Td/1/)